# speed of c++ addons for node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, performance

I made two similar codes on c++ and node.js, that just work with strings. I have this in .js file:

```
//some code, including f
console.time('c++');
console.log(addon.sum("123321", s));
console.timeEnd('c++');
console.time('js');
console.log(f("123321", s));
console.timeEnd('js');
```

and my c++ addon looks like that:

```
//some code, including f
void Sum(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args)
{
    v8::Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    v8::String::Utf8Value str0(isolate, args[0]);
    v8::String::Utf8Value str1(isolate, args[1]);
    string a(*str0), b(*str1);
    string s2 = f(a, b);
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, s2.c_str()).ToLocalChecked());
}
```

but the problem is that c++ works nearly 1.5 times slower, than js, even though the function on JS has some parts, that can be optimised (I did not write it very accurately).
In the console I get

```
@uTMTahdZ22d!a_ah(3(_Zd_]Zc(tJT[263mca!(jcT[20_]h0h_06q(0jJ(T]!&]qZM]d_30j&Tuj2hm[Z0d@!32ccT2(!dud@6]0MdJc]mta!3]j]_(hhJqha(([
c++: 7.970s
@uTMTahdZ22d!a_ah(3(_Zd_]Zc(tJT[263mca!(jcT[20_]h0h_06q(0jJ(T]!&]qZM]d_30j&Tuj2hm[Z0d@!32ccT2(!dud@6]0MdJc]mta!3]j]_(hhJqha(([
js: 5.062s
```

So, the results of functions are similar, but the JS program ran a lot faster. How can it be? Shouldn't c++ faster than JS (at least not so much slower)? Maybe I did not took in account an important detail, that slows c++ so much, or working with strings is really so slow in c++?

Comment: Write it in pure C++, and not as a plugin for notejs. As it is now, it seems you wrote a plugin in C++ that tells the javascript engine to do some stuff. Highly unlikely that this will be efficient.

Comment: I want to rewrite js code to c++ to make it work faster. I managed to do that easily with numbers, but now with strings I have this problem. I will try to write this function in pure c++ and see the performance. I will send it in a few w minutes

Comment: I do not know how, but on pure c++ this function took even more time. I changed constants, and pure c++ took `1.689s`, when `c++ addon: 204.53ms` and
`js: 148.073ms`.

Comment: How have you compiled your C++ code? It is the first question you should answer when you compare functions.

Comment: Using node-gyp and then just requiring the native code in js file

Answer (score 0):

First off, the Javascript interpreter is pretty advanced in what types of optimizations it can do (actually compiling Javascript code to native code in some cases) which significantly reduces the differences between Javascript and C++ compared to what most people would think.

Second, crossing the C++/Javascript boundary has some overhead cost associated with it as you marshall the function arguments in between the Javascript world and the C++ world (creating copies, doing heap operations, etc...).  So, if that overhead is significant relative to the execution of the operation, then it can negate your advantages to going to C++ in the first place.

For more detailed comments, we would need to see the actual implementation of `f()` in both Javascript and C++.

Comment: I deleted all data passing between c++ and js, it reduced c++ time a bit, but it is still a lot longer than js. And from the first part, even though the optimisation is good, shouldn’t c++ work at least nearly the same time as js. How can node, written on c++ (as I know) be faster than c++ itself?

Comment: @ALEX - You don't show us the majority of the operative code here (the implementation of `f()` in both langauges) so there's not much we can really comment on beyond the calling overhead.

Comment: here, I uploaded it to gitHub: https://github.com/TTPO100AJIEX/c-VSjs . As I said, it is just a lot of string work (even a bit inaccurate on js)